# Truffle how to test with reference to mainnet smart contract - Error: while migrating VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-test, mainnet

I would like to run a truffle test on a smart contract that includes a smart contract address deployed on mainnet. However, this results in the following error

`Error: Error: Error: while migrating WhitelistAdvanced: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

It seems like the migration process running before the actual test fails because the mainnet contract can obviously not be found on my local test chain.

```
contract WhitelistAdvanced {
    Whitelist internal whitelistContract = Whitelist(0x6198149b79AFE8114dc07b46A01d94a6af304ED9);

    constructor() public {
        address[] memory subscriberList = whitelistContract.getSubscriberList();
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < subscriberList.length; i++) {
            _subscribe(subscriberList[i]);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
deploy_contracts.js

```
const Whitelist = artifacts.require("Whitelist");
const WhitelistAdvanced = artifacts.require("WhitelistAdvanced");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Whitelist);
  deployer.deploy(WhitelistAdvanced);
};
```

EDIT:
console output

```
$ truffle test test/TESTWhitelistAdvanced.js 

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/Whitelist.sol
> Compiling ./contracts/WhitelistAdvanced.sol

Error: Error: Error: while migrating WhitelistAdvanced: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at Object.run (/Users/X/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.4/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-migrate/index.js:92:1)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
Truffle v5.0.33 (core: 5.0.33)
Node v8.9.4
```

Comment: Please share the relevant Truffle test and all of your Truffle migration scripts.

Comment: @goodvibration I update the migration file. However, the tests are irrelevant because the error happens already before the actually tests run.

Comment: Then prevent them from running during `truffle test`, and instantiate them yourself in each one of your tests as needed.

Comment: @goodvibration sorry, I probably didn't make the question clear. The error happens for the migration already, which is just the step before the actual test. Meaning `truffle migrate` will result in an error as well.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make myself clear - prevent your migration scripts from running during `truffle test`, and the problem is solved. While your migration scripts are designated to run on mainnet, `truffle test` is obviously not. It therefore seems like the right thing to do. If you want to know how, then check [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/49721/16043) (which I asked here myself a while ago).

Comment: And if you're looking for a solution, then I recently posted it [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/75957/16043).

Comment: @goodvibration Got ya. :) Thanks. Not the solution I was looking for but will do for now!

Comment: @goodvibration Sorry, I think my problem still exists. I prevent `truffle test` from running a migration and deploy the contract within the test myself. However, it will of course throw the same error since the constructor uses a smart contract, which only exist on the mainnet. Advice?

Comment: Advice: Don't use mainnet addresses in your Truffle tests! The whole idea about a Truffle test is that you execute it "locally" (i.e., on a private network), in order to test a contract before deploying it to mainnet.

Comment: @goodvibration agree but what if I want to get data from a mainnet contract for the test? Not possible?

Comment: You can create another `Web3` instance connected to mainnet, in order to **read** data from there.

Comment: BTW, your previous comment is misleading. I believe that `it will of course throw the same error` is incorrect. You should be getting an error which is different from what's described in your question.

Comment: @goodvibration true. It still reverts but it's probably a different error message.